# windows phone 7.5 create big tiles (1x2 , 2x1)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I know you can create tiles from your application in windows phone 7.5. 
I'm interested in how to create big tile like the picture tile or the Samsung Hub tile ( that expend over the size of 2 tile horizontally or vertically).
I's there any public api to do this? (with out using native code)?

thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An application on the Marketplace can not create wide tiles. Builders are the only ones who can do that currently.

> Windows Phone devices come with some Start Tiles already installed by Microsoft and its mobile operator and hardware manufacturer partners. These Tiles consistently follow the Metro style. **Double-width Tiles are available only to Microsoft and its partners.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202884(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 6):

This won't pass certification, for the reason provided by Julien, however you can play with the WMAppManifest.xml by altering the TemplateType, as detailed in the following :-

http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=207

Just to repeat, this won't pass certification.